# 2007 Toyota Camry "Check VSC System" and Check Engine Light On

Tags: toyota, camry

When i started my car today morning, I saw "Check VSC System" and then it has the check engine light and slippery indicator light on.

About three months ago, I had "Check VSC System" with check engine light ON. I checked the code in Autozone and found that O2 sensor1 was bad. I replaced it.

I live in Minnesota, where we had a snow blizzard this last weekend (4/13/2018). Not sure why VSC(Vehicle Stability Control Light) has come on again.

I searched online, I found that it could be an ABS sensor. Anyone else had this issue during snowy cold weather? Should I worry and check those codes or just turn it off watching a YouTube video?

**EDIT - 1**

I went to Toyota and checked the code, it was **C1201** and another warning I had was gas cap might not have closed well, which causes bad circulation. The Toyota guy googled this code right away and said it might be a break fluid issue. He opened the hood, break fluid was not at the max (little lower than max limit). Then, he topped it off and turned the warning off.

I was googling myself, I found so many threads, most of them were associated with **C1201** and **C1202**.  Not sure, which one to trust on.

**EDIT - 2**

If anyone come across the same issue, [this](https://www.autocodes.com/c1201_toyota.html) might be helpful. 
It was "Sequential Multi port Fuel Injection (SFI) System Problems"

Comment: I had the vsc light and check engine light on at one point. I pulled the codes and it was totally unrelated to the vsc system. The CEL comes on when codes are stored. The only way to know the problem is to pull the codes. For some reason, toyota turns both lights on for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Check VSC System" indicator could very well be triggered by blizzard conditions, as an ABS sensor can get fouled by snow and ice buildup preventing the system from reading wheel speeds correctly.
Let the car thaw out and reset the code if needed, if the check light stays off during driving you're fine.
If the check light comes right back on then probably an ABS wheel sensor needs replacement, or some other problems are present in the system.

Edit:
After some googling it seems that the C1201 code often goes together with engine related fault codes. The reason for this seems to be Toyota's philosophy that if engine power output cannot be reliably determined (due to whatever engine related error code), you should also lose traction control and so C1201 is also trigged. Fix any other issues and C1201 will disappear and your VSC light will go off.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to reset the lights. Since weather is getting a little nicer today, hope it'll get better and doesn't turn on again. Is it still safe to drive since you talked about ABS sensor?

Comment: You can still drive the car, but be especially careful in slippery conditions as your anti-lock brakes and vehicle stability control system might not function.

Comment: The Toyota guy should better have left the brake fluid alone, as it is normal to be 'below maximum'. Now the next time that someone want to change brake pads the brake fluid reservoir is likely to overflow. But thats a different story...

Please add the information about the error codes to your question and i'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I finally, found [this](https://www.autocodes.com/c1201_toyota.html)  that could be more relevant to my issue. Engine Control System Malfunction. As mentioned in the edit, there was another error about gas cap might not have been tighten well. Thank for the edit.